# В Android Studio сворачивается код

Tags: android-studio, ide, intellij-idea, jetbrains

Здравствуйте!
Разрабатываю приложение в Android Studio и очень бесит автосворачивание кода.
Выглядит это так:

[image: before click]

Если щелкнуть ЛКМ по нему, то он раскрывается:

[image: after click]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить эту функцию.

Comment: Ну не знаю. Мне наоборот нравится. Это как я понимаю "подготовка" к closure/lambda в Java 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отключается вот этой опцией:

[image: clojures]